# cocoapods linker error when i added it to my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, linker-errors, cocoapods

i'm using cocoapods for the first time and after everything goes well 
i get to run my project that was always wor˚ and got those 2 errors in lin˚er

can anyone please tell me what is it

than˚s

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PECropViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in addProductViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: if you open the project from .xcodeproj file, that may be reason. You must use .workspace file to work on project for projects using cocoapods. (just a reminder).

Comment: @meth i open it in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addProductViewController` object is not found and it was referenced within `AppDelegate`. You do not link `addProductViewController` into your app. Check if your Compile Sources section within the Build Phases of your project shows `addProductViewController.m`

Comment: add product was already there and was wor˚ing fine this all happened when i used cocoapods and import the library i installed in addProductViewController

Answer (score 0):

than˚s every body for your help

the problem was with arm 64 i just added it in my target and everything work fine 
in architectures filed add standard architectures armv7,arm64